# Licensing SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services w/ SharePoint 2010

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010, licensing, ssrs, sql-server-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Here's my situation:
I have 1 VM that is running SharePoint 2010 SP1. I have a different physical server that is running SQL Server 2008 R2 that hosts all the configuration and content database for SharePoint.

Now, we want to start providing BI capabilities to our users with SharePoint and SQL Server. With it's new features, 2012 is the obvious way to go. To support this, I'm looking to build a new VM that will have SQL Server 2012 installed w/ Analysis services and SSIS, which will be the platform that gets our data from our Oracle databases, puts it in a warehouse hosted by the SQL 2012 instance, and is put into cubes.

What's getting me about the platform is licensing for Reporting Services and PowerPivot. My plan was to install SSRS and PowerPivot on the current SharePoint server. But my understanding of the licensing means that instead of the new SQL server being licensed, I'd have to license both new server, and the SharePoint server. Conversely, I could install SharePoint onto the SQL server, and only have to get a second SP license, but then I'd have the added complexity of deploying a separated application server, and combines my data and application servers.

Is my licensing understanding correct, or can I have SSRS and PowerPivot installed separately without incurring additional licensing costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the answer comes a bit late, here's some info in case someone else has the same question:

In SQL Server 2012, Reporting Services is classified as "Additional Software". This means that it can be installed on any computer without requiring an extra SQL Server license (much like the Client Tools). In your situation, this means that you can install SSRS on the SharePoint server, and still only need 1 license for SQL and 1 for SharePoint.

More info:

https://mikesnotebook.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/ssrs-2012-licensing/
http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/DocumentSearch.aspx?Mode=3&DocumentTypeId=1

Unfortunately, the same does not apply to PowerPivot. I'm not familiar with the PowerPivot install - does this also require that SharePoint and the PowerPivot server run on the same machine? If not, you could get away with the following setup:

- Server 1: SQL Server, SSAS, SSIS, PowerPivot
- Server 2: SSRS, SharePoint

This only requires one license for SQL, and one for SharePoint.

Comment: It looks like Microsoft reneged on this a few months after your original answer and you now do need a separate SQL license if you have SSRS running on a separate server (see the updated info in your first link for details)